# Filter function that show / hide markers accordingly when filtering

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I need to create a search-filter function that show/hide google map markers accordingly to the filter.
For example, if i type "a" in my search form, the map will display only those markers that contain an "a", while the other remain hidden.
I'm using JS and knockout framework. I was thinking to use Marker.setVisible(true/false) but i do not know how to implement this feature.
Thanks for your help

```
var Data = {
            locations: [

            new Location("Palazzo Pitti", 43.765264, 11.250094,"4bc8c9d7af07a593d4aa812d"),
            new Location("Uffizi Gallery", 43.768439, 11.2559,"51191cdfb0ed67c8fff5610b"),
            new Location("Florence Cathedral", 43.773083, 11.256222,"4bd00cdb046076b00a576f71"),
            new Location("Palazzo Vecchio", 43.769315, 11.256174,"4bd01b8077b29c74a0298a82"),
            new Location("Piazza della Signoria", 43.7684152597, 11.2534589862,"4b81729af964a520a7a630e3"),
            new Location("Giotto's Campanile", 43.772772, 11.255786,"4b49cd73f964a520d87326e3"),
            new Location("Piazzale Michelangelo", 43.762462, 11.264897,"4b3276d5f964a520620c25e3"),
            new Location("Ponte Vecchio", 43.768009, 11.253165,"4b6ed35df964a52038cc2ce3"),
            new Location("Boboli Gardens", 43.762361, 11.248297,"4bc97abcfb84c9b6f62e1b3e"),
            new Location("Vinci", 43.783333, 10.916667,"4ca4f0a0965c9c74530dc7fa"),
            ],
            query: ko.observable(''),
        };

        // Search by name into the locations list.
        Data.search = ko.computed(function() {
         var self = this;
         var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
         return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.locations, function(location) {
         return location.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
        });}, Data);

        ko.applyBindings(Data);
        }
```

Comment: What do you expect from us?

Comment: I was trying something like that, but it returns an error:                                                                                                                   var isMatching = location.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;

        if (isMatching) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }

        return isMatching;
    });

Comment: There is a .filter function on any array object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close to what you need.  Remember that locations is a `ko.observable`, so you need to use parens to open it up.  Try this:

```
Data.search = ko.computed(function() {
    var self = this;
    var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.locations, function(location) {
        if (location.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0) {
            location.setVisible(true);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            place.setVisible(false);
            return false;
        }            
    });
}, Data);  // not sure you really need this last reference to Data here
```